# inspect module with compiled python files

Tags: python, python-2.7, inspect

I have two files caller.py and callee.py

caller.py

```
## 
##     
##     
##     
##   
##   
##
##
##
from callee import fn
def caller():
  fn()

caller()
```

callee.py

```
import inspect
def fn():
  print inspect.stack()
```

Now I compiled both `caller.py` and `callee.py` to get the corresponding `pyc` files and moved them to a new directory `compiled`.
This is the directory structure.

```
├── __init__.py
├── callee.py
├── caller.py
└── compiled
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── callee.pyc
    └── caller.pyc
```

I modified caller.py to remove all the comments, resulting in:
caller.py

```
from callee import fn
def caller():
  fn()

caller()
```

When I execute `python compiled/caller.pyc`
This is the error thrown

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "caller.py", line 73, in
>
> File "caller.py", line 71, in caller
>
> File "callee.py", line 4, in fn
>
> File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 1062, in stack
>       return getouterframes(sys._getframe(1), context)
>    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 1040, in getouterframes
>       framelist.append((frame,) + getframeinfo(frame, context))
>    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 1015, in getframeinfo
>       lines, lnum = findsource(frame)
>    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 579, in findsource
>       if pat.match(lines[lnum]): break
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Looks like inspect is trying to read from the source file `.py` even though it is in a different directory.
This error does not seem to occur when I navigate to some other directory.

What is the explanation for this? Does inspect.stack() look for the filename’s (caller.pyc) `py` equivalent in the current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Python looks for suitable modules based on its `PATH`, and the first place it looks for them is in the folder you are when you launch the program.

If you want the interpreter to ignore the original source files, move to the directory where the `.pyc` files are and launch the script with `python caller.pyc`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! 
But this seems contradicting to the way `import` works. `import` appropriately imports from the `pyc` files present in the `compiled` directory.

Comment: No, `import` still follows the rule that I wrote above. Also I have to say it's a bit weird (as far as I know) to have the compiled files in a different folder, since usually they're just an optimization (they are recompiled every time you change something in the original file).

Comment: Also, the very first error message you get seems to imply that the file `caller.py` is used...

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I tried adding debug statements (printing) in the `py` files. 
The import statement imports from the `pyc` files and not the `py` files. 

Also, the reason I am asking this is, I have an `egg` that has `pyc` files. The egg is added to `path` but there are also corresponding `py` (older versions with lesser lines) files residing outside the egg. 
I'm encountering the same error when a file inside the egg is doing an `inspect.stack()`